# Autogenerate numeric columns based on another column's values

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table with two columns, one column is "State" and the other is "State Number".

I would need to have the column "State Number" have numeric values based on the values of the column "State", alphabetically.

example...

```
State = A is equals to State Number = 1
State = B is equals to State Number = 2
State = C is equals to State Number = 3
```

So and and so forth.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should try with a trigger

Comment: @Yoleth, no, you can't use recursive trigger in MySQL.

Comment: where is the data currently? is it in the table? I mean State having values and State Number is empty/null.... or your table is empty and you need to load it?

Comment: Hi!

The State column is  filled up, but the State Number column is empty, and that's the one I need to sequence numerically, alphabetically basing on the values of the State column

Answer (score 1):

NO, you can't do it automatically other than defining `State Number` to be `auto_increment`. What you are asking can be done using trigger but `MySQL` doesn't support recursive trigger and thus it's not an option here.

You can perform an `UPDATE` though using `CASE` condition and update the said column like

```
update tbl1
set `State Number` = case when state = 'A' then 1
                     when state = 'B' then 2
                     when state = 'C' then 3 end;
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, thank you for the answer.

I guess I would have a hard time doing this then, since there are around 400-500 city values that I need to pair them up with a state number